# How can I prevent styles from applying to certain HTML snippets?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating documentation for some reusable components. The documentation page will include a demo of the component along with documentation for how to re-create it. For example, I may be demonstrating this HTML:

```
<div class="top-level">
    <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

Which has this CSS:

```
.top-level { background: red; }
```

Now, I'd like to have an aside that documents how to create re-create it:

```
<aside>
    <p>All top level content goes into a div with a class of "top-level:</p>
    <code><div class="top-level"></div></code>
</aside>
```

The problem is that the text between the "code" tags is still picking up the styling for div.top-level. I'd like it to display simply as code. I'm sure I can just override everything, but is anyone aware of a more elegant solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Give them different classes of create a more specific rule to override the other rule.

Comment: instead of `<div class="top-level"></div>` use                 `&lt;div class="top-level"&gt;&lt;/div&gt` inside your `code`-tags. That should solve the problem.

Comment: @LifeInTheGrey That is wrong. `<code>` is a phrase-tag. Means its purpose is to make a visual differentiation that the user can easier see that it is code. It translates nothing for you.

Comment: @LifeInTheGrey- Nope, you have to HTML encode html even in the context of a <code> block, if you want the browser to render it literally. One of myriad ways to get the encoded text is http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any code to appear on a Web page should be placed inside a `<code>` element. Usually the content of the `<code>` element is presented in a monospaced font, just like the code in most programming books.

But you must still escape your `<` and `>` (`&lt;`,`&gt;`), that the browser knows that you don't want the tags rendered out as html.

The correct expression between your `<code>` tags would be `&lt;div class="top-level"&gt;&lt;/div&gt`.